# Animating button position based on height of accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two buttons, one on top of the other, that are fixed on the right hand side of the page. I have it so when a user clicks on the top button, it slides out content to the left, and animates the second button to below content so it is still visible to the user. The content displayed is actually an accordion with collapsible panels, so when a user clicks on a `accordion-control` button, it hides the currently displayed content, and shows the requested content.

**Issue**

The second button moves according to the height of the accordion content above it, only if I select one `accordion-control` to open and close. When I select a different `accordion-control`, it adds to the `position: top` of the second button, pushing it further down the page, rather than subtracting from the `position:top`, thus keeping it in align with the above content.

**Aim**

To have the second button consistently located below the accordion content above it, based on the height of the content, no matter what `accordion-control` the user selects.

**JSFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/patrickmcd121/55am802a/2/

**jQuery for accordion functionality**

```
$(function() {
    $('.accordion-control').click(function() {
        if($(this).next('.accordion-panel').hasClass('active')) {
            $('.active').removeClass('active').slideUp(); //if current accord-control is clicked twice
        } else {
            $('.active').removeClass('active').slideUp();
            $(this).next('.accordion-panel').addClass('active').slideDown();
        }
 });
})
```

**jQuery to position the second button**

```
$('#faqSlider .accordion-control').click(function() {

    var accord_panel = $(this).next('.accordion-panel');
    var accord_panel_height = accord_panel.outerHeight();

    console.log(accord_panel.text());

    if((!accord_panel.is(':visible')) && (!(accord_panel).is(':animated'))) {
        $('#guideSlider, #guideSlider-button').animate({'top': '+='+(accord_panel_height)});    
    } else {
        if (!(accord_panel).is(':animated')) {
            $('#guideSlider, #guideSlider-button').animate({'top': '-='+(accord_panel_height)});
        }   //carry on monday, issue with button below moving down
    }
})
```

---

```
<aside>         
<div id="faqSlider-button">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>                   
    <p class="no-margin-bottom">FAQ</p>
</div>

<div id="guideSlider-button">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>                   
    <p class="no-margin-bottom">Guide</p>
</div>
<div id="faqSlider">
    <ul class="accordion no-padding no-margin-bottom">
        <li>
            <button class="accordion-control text-md-left">1. Lorem Ipsum</button>
            <div class="accordion-panel">
                <ul class="no-padding">
                    <li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</li></li>
                    <li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</li></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button class="accordion-control text-md-left">2. Lorem Ipsum</button>
            <div class="accordion-panel">
                <ul class="no-padding">
                    <li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</li></li>
                    <li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</li></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button class="accordion-control text-md-left">3. Lorem Ipsum</button>
            <div class="accordion-panel">
                <ul class="no-padding">
                    <li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</li></li>
                    <li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</li></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>                                   
    </ul>
</div>                  
<div id="guideSlider">
    <ul class="accordion no-padding no-margin-bottom">
        <li>
            <button class="accordion-control text-md-left">1. Create your User Profile</button>
            <div class="accordion-panel">
                <ul class="no-padding">
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button class="accordion-control text-md-left">2. Add the details of your Care Receivers (you can store up to four)</button>
            <div class="accordion-panel">
                <ul class="no-padding">
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button class="accordion-control text-md-left">3. Create the profiles for your Responders (you can choose up to five for each Care Receiver)</button>
            <div class="accordion-panel">
                <ul class="no-padding">
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>                           
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

```
.accordion li { list-style: none; }
.accordion button:focus { outline-color: #E6E8E3; } 
.accordion-panel li:before { 
content: url('../imgs/dash-point.png');
padding-right: 1rem;
}
.accordion-panel { display: none; padding: 1rem; background: #fff}
.accordion-control {
background: #fff;
border: 1px solid #E6E8E3;
padding: 1rem;
width: 100%;
}

.accordion-control:hover, .accordion-control.active 
{ cursor: pointer; background: #eeeeee; }
```

Comment: Could you try to add your code as `snippet` or `fiddle` because when I tried to replicate this in `fiddle`, I just couldn't relate this with the design you are mentioning in the question.. Also, try to name your buttons [second and first] in the question.. :)

Comment: **[Here is what I could achieve or replicate](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/krt6jtjw/)**.

Comment: Bare with me I'll get you a JSFiddle

Comment: Yes please.. Let me know once done..

Comment: One small query. You want to align second button under the first button or the div content of first button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my observations and solution for your problem.

- First thing that came into my notice is that, the mis-calculation of `bottom` value of an `element` [top `panel`] which has to be assigned to `top` value of corresponding `element` [second `button`]. You were calculating `bottom` value by adding `#faqSlider`'s - `height` and  `outerheight` of `button` referred as `this` which would give you some wrong number and which will be set to `top` of second `button`.
- On the second note, the calculation was going wrong because, the animation that would extend `width` and `height` of top `panel` and the value for `top` of the second `button` was happening concurrently. So proper value was not fetched while calculating the `faq_slider_height`.
- Lastly, you were storing the values of `height` and `width` of `faqSlider` globally which was changing during the course of `animation` and hence the same was not reflected in the `variables` everytime and remained constant.

---

**Resolution on point 1**

To set `top` value for any `element`, by referring `bottom` value of other `element` you need to calculate the `bottom` value of reference `element` which would be `$("#reference_element_id").offset().top + $("#reference_element_id").outerHeight()`.

**Resolution on point 2**

Since animation takes some `milliseconds` to complete roughly within `500 milliseconds` or some custom value set by you, the calculation of `top` value and setting `top` value should be done after few milliseconds. The best approach I suggest here is using `setTimeout` with a minimum value of `300 milliseconds`.

**Resolution of point 3**

Declare `var faq_slider_width, faq_slider_height;` globally and update their values during certain changes.

**Conclusion**

To conclude, here is the complete first `button click event` code and **[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/krt6jtjw/1/)**

```
var faq_slider_width,faq_slider_height;

$('#faqSlider-button').click(function() {
    $('#faqSlider .accordion-panel').hide(300);
    if($(this).css("margin-right") == (faq_slider_width)+"px" && !$(this).is(':animated')) {            
        $(this).removeClass('open');
        setTimeout(function(){
            faq_slider_width = $('#faqSlider').outerWidth();//get width automaticly
            faq_slider_height = $('#faqSlider').outerHeight();
            $('#faqSlider, #faqSlider-button').animate({"margin-right": '-='+(faq_slider_width)}, 800, function() {
                $('#guideSlider, #guideSlider-button').animate({'top': '10rem'}, 400);
            });
        },300);
    } else {
        if(!$(this).is(':animated')) {//prevent double click to double margin   
            $(this).addClass('open');
            setTimeout(function(){
                faq_slider_width = $('#faqSlider').outerWidth();//get width automaticly
                faq_slider_height = $('#faqSlider').outerHeight();
                $('#guideSlider, #guideSlider-button').animate({'top': (faq_slider_height + $("#faqSlider").offset().top + 20 + 'px')}, 300);
                $('#faqSlider, #faqSlider-button').animate({"margin-right": '+='+(faq_slider_width)}, 800);
            },300);

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the time you've taken to answer and thank you for explaining the different resolutions. However, it still has the same issue, with the button being further pushed down the page, rather than staying with the bottom of the above content. You see in your fiddle how you click on the first button and the content shows? And the second button then moves down, when you click on another tab, the guide button continues to move down the page, where I need it to stick to the bottom of the first buttons content. Sorry if I'm making it sound complicated

Comment: Did you check the `jsfiddle` specified in the answer. I would be more helpful if I get to see the actual content..

Comment: Yeah I checked your fiddle. If you are looking at your fiddle, you have the two buttons on the right, FAQ and Guide. Click on FAQ, opens fine and pushes the guide button down. Click on '1. Lorem Ipsum', opens and pushes the guide button down. If you were to then click '2. Lorem Ipsum', do you see how the guide button is pushed further down, rather than sticking where it is?

Comment: I should have updated this in my answer. I have noticed the said issue before posting but thought you might get it from the **problems identified** and **resolutions provided**. Now if you read carefully, you need to do the same calculations for `faq_slider_width, faq_slider_height` while clicking on buttons too as it gets updated too in this scenario and that's what I meant by **update their values during certain changes** on my **Resolution 3** :)

Comment: I'll carry on working on it incorporating your methods. Nearly there... I hope. Thanks again.... may call on you in an hour if still struggling

Comment: Finally!! As you said, 'read carfully'. Thank you Guruprasad Rao! Thought I was going to lose my mind at one point

Comment: Anytime buddy.. Happy coding.. :)